# Did the Black Death affect Muslim's prayers in the mosque?

Tags: islamic-history, muslims

How did the black death affect Muslims? Were they not allowed to go pray in the mosques? So if Muslims where not allowed to go to the mosque how did they complete their prayers?

Comment: Yes, dead people usually don't pray.

Comment: See [What were the effects of the Black Death in the Muslim world?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35654/what-were-the-effects-of-the-black-death-in-the-muslim-world/46121#46121).